# Ignoring the header line of an array read from CSV file outputting in XML format

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, csv

I'm trying to read in but not output the header line of this csv file attached. In other words, reading the header line in and ignoring it before processing the data lines.

namespace csvtoXML
{
    class Program
    {

```
    static void Main( string[] args)
    {




    string[] source = File.ReadAllLines("GBPAY_103188.csv");
    XElement GBPAY = new XElement("EmployeeElectionImport",
        from str in source
        let fields = str.Split(',')
                  select new XElement("ElectionImport",
                  new XElement("EmployeeElection",
                  new XElement("Employee",fields[0]),
                  new XElement("Election", "\n",
                  new XElement("EarnDeductType", fields[3]),
                  new XElement("EarnDeductType","\n",
                  new XElement("PlanBenefitCode", fields[1], "\n"),
                  new XElement("SingleFamilyCode", fields[2], "\n"),
                  new XElement("EERate", fields[3], "\n"),
                   new XElement("ERRate", fields[4], "\n"),
                   new XElement("AnnualBenefitRate", fields[5], "\n"),
                   new XElement("EnrollmentCode", fields[6], "\n")
                ))))) ; ;
            Console.WriteLine(GBPAY);
}}}
```

Comment: You could use `source.Skip(1)`

Comment: critical thinking is key. You're using the ReadAllLines method, which will read all lines. Is there any way to NOT read all lines, and skip the first line? OR, you could modify the array prior to processing removing the first line, OR you are using a LINQ query to get all elements in the array. Is there any way to SKIP certain elements while selecting from a source?

Comment: Hmm so there is no way to read the header lines but also ignore outputting them at the same time? @Jeremy

Comment: I think you missed my point. the answer to all of questions is YES, there is a way. There is a ReadLines method which lets you build your array the way you want. there is a way to SKIP selecting things in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of read all lines, you should:
have to read one line at a time, and only output the lines you want.
An example on how to this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time)